# How to check for the date and time in javascript asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, date

I have a text box using jquery date and time iam choosing a date and time so this will be in my text box `2014/06/11 18:50` On submit button i am calling a javascript

```
 <asp:Button ID="bt_schedule" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="return btnSubmit_Click();" 
                            OnClick="bt_schedule_Click" />
```

**my requirement is date should be greater than and equal to today's date and time should be greater than 5 minute  to current time.** so i am using something like below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function btnSubmit_Click() {

                var strval = document.getElementById("<%= tb_calimage.ClientID %>").value;
                var dateParts = strval.split(" ");
                var date = dateParts[0];
                var time = dateParts[1];
                var datecompare = new Date(date);
                var currentDate = new Date();

 var sysdate = currentDate.getHours();
                var systime = currentDate.getMinutes();
                if (datecompare >= currentDate ) {
                    alert('Date greater than or equal t0 Today');
                    return false;
                } 

                return true;
            }
```

and also currentDate  is showing date with time so i am not able to get it properly.. and also how to check with time. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, your current format of string is good to go.

So, if in Javascript you write:

```
var requestedDate = new Date("2014/06/11 18:50");

var oldDate = new Date("2014/06/11 18:45");
```

and try to do a subtraction.

`var val = requestedDate-oldDate;`

`val` would be: `300000`.

Extending this further you could just use `var oldDate = new Date()`

and check if `val>300000`, then you have a time greater than 5 minutes from now :)

**Complete code:**

```
function btnSubmit_Click() {

                var strval = document.getElementById("<%= tb_calimage.ClientID %>").value;
                var datecompare = new Date(strval);
                var currentDate = new Date();
                if (datecompare-currentDate <300000 ) {
                    alert('Please select date-time more than 5 minutes from now.');
                    return false;
                } 

                return true;
            }
```